# Allowing an internal site URL as well as web-visible site URL in app config

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, dns, internal

I've read around but I can't find any similar questions so here goes...

I have a facebook application which is configured and working fine, Lets take my website URL to be:

```
http://adminpanel.its.a.very.long.url.mywebsite.com
```

This is configured as the 'site URL' in the application config and it works fine.

However, the website is also used on our internal network with a DNS that allows us to use

```
http://adminpanel/
```

The problem is that the facebook app wont allow a'redirect_uri' to be

```
http://adminpanel/
```

and fails with the following:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.

Is it possible to allow both

```
http://adminpanel.its.a.very.long.url.mywebsite.com
```

and

```
http://adminpanel/
```

Thanks in advance,

Oli

**UPDATE**: I can't use two apps as I rely the 'Add Page Tab Dialogue' to add my application to various Pages.

What I need is both of these redirects (specified by the 'next' param) to be allowed by facebook.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=12345678&display=popup&next=http://adminpanel/Success

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=12345678&display=popup&next=http://adminpanel.its.a.very.long.url.mywebsite.com/Success

Answer (score 0):

A common problem, and it's easy to fix. Check out my PHP code below:

```
if ( strstr( 'adminpanel', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
    // this is the localhost settings

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
    ));

    $app_url = 'http://adminpanel/';
    $fb_url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/';

    //  other settings can go here too

} else {
    // this is the main / live site settings

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'yyy',
        'secret' => 'yyy',
    ));

    $app_url = 'http://adminpanel.its.a.very.long.url.mywebsite.com';
    $fb_url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/yyy';

    //  other settings can go here too

}
```

Problem solved!

The code checks to see which `host` its running on and loads the correct settings for each. You will need to have two different versions of the App on Facebook. This will let you configure the URLs for each app separately (as in the PHP code above).

If you are using a different language, you can easily do the same thing by detecting the `host` and putting your config settings in the relevant part of the conditional statement. It will even allow you to configure multiple (i.e. more than 2) environments.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but I think your answer is a solution to a different scenario. I have added more detail in the question to hopefully make it clear of my intentions. Cheers!

Comment: Using one app for two locations isn't something Facebook supports. You can try adding the two URLs to the `App Domains` field in the App Settings but Facebook will only redirect users back to the URLs listed in the App Settings. Adding multiple domains might fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried adding http://adminpanel (and just 'adminpanel') to the App Domain section but facebook doesn't allow it.

App Domains: adminpanel is not a valid domain.

Comment: There is another option. Create a VHOST on your localmachine and call it `adminpanel.com`. Then edit the host file on your machine to redirect `adminpanel.com` to `127.0.0.1`. Then update the app config to point the FB app to `adminpanel.com` like you did before. It will trick Facebook into thinking it's a valid domain, and your locally hosted code will still work.

Comment: Sorry the code isn't locally hosted on each terminal so this isn't a suitable option I'm afraid. Thanks again. Oliver